# Can I set a custom location for ~/snap folder?

Tags: home-directory, snap, default

I've installed a snap-packaged application, which has in turn created a folder called ~/snap.

Is it possible to move this folder somewhere else? For example, by setting an environment variable?

Comment: Best to go to https://forum.snapcraft.io/ which is the snap forum and add yourself to those who want this feature.